# Replacing elements in a list with a value in a dictionary

Tags: python

The goal is to input a chemical compound, such as C6H12O6, and return the atomic weight and the names of the chemical in the compound. I've figured out how to find the atomic weight, but I can't figure out how to print the names of the elements. I've put all of the symbols in a dictionary as the key, with the value being a tuple with weight as the first index and the name as the second.

I've tried making a for loop that will go through every element of the list and then replace that element with the name in the dictionary.

```
    import re
    def makeDictionary:()
        mydict={}
        inFile = open("atomic_weights.txt")
        for line in inFile:
            line = line.strip()
            (weight,symbol,name) = line.split("\t")
            mydict[symbol]=(float(weight),name)
    return mydict

    def splitCompound(mydict):
        compound=input("Chemical composition?")
        #this separates the symbols and the numbers in the compound
        elements = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)',compound)
        elementsUsed=[]
        for i in elements:
            myElement=i[0]
            elementsUsed.append(myElement)
        i=0 
        while i<len(elementsUsed):
            names=mydict[myElement][1]
            i+=1
        print(elementsUsed)
        print(names)

    def main():
        mydict = makeDictionary()
        splitCompound(mydict)

    main()
```

If I input "H2O" then my elementsUsed list prints: ['H','O'] but my names list only prints "Oxygen" when I want it to print ['Hydrogen','Oxygen'].
Basically, it's only replacing the last element of the list with the chemical name instead of every element in my elementsUsed list.

Comment: You are replacing `names` each loop iteration: `names=mydict[myElement][1]`. Make `names` a list *first*, then append to that list each iteration.

Comment: You're overwriting `names`, rather than appending to a list, so you'll always end up with just the last one.